# Excel 2007: Array formula lookup using INDEX and MATCH is only looking at first row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet, "2011-11", with a series of numbers in column C. The numbers are each in a given currency, identified by a code in column B. What I want to do is write a single formula (in cell C14) that will convert each number (from C4:C13) into pounds sterling (GBP) by dividing it by the relevant exchange rate, then take the sum of these numbers.

The exchange rates are stored on a separate worksheet, "GBP". The rate changes each month so there is a table with the currency codes listed vertically and the month listed horizontally.

I have a formula which, for a single cell C4, correctly looks up the exchange rate:

```
=INDEX(GBP!$A$4:$BE$42,MATCH($B4,GBP!$A$4:$A$42,0),MATCH(DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),31),GBP!$A$3:$CE$3,1))
```

So I had hoped that by changing the reference range in the first `MATCH` to point to `$B4:$B13`, inserting the whole thing into a `SUM` formula, and entering it as an array formula, I would get the right answer:

```
{=SUM(C4:C13/INDEX(GBP!$A$4:$BE$42,MATCH($B4:$B13,GBP!$A$4:$A$42,0),MATCH(DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),31),GBP!$A$3:$CE$3,1)))}
```

However, whilst it is nearly there, this is applying the exchange rate for row 4 to each row. Help much appreciated! Can it be done, or do I need to insert an extra column?

A couple of extra notes:

1. I tried using `SUMPRODUCT` instead of `SUM`, but this made no difference
2. The value of A1 is "2011-11"

Comment: I have not looked very carefully at your problem but I notice that your formula is full of $s which means do not adjust the target.  Could this be your problem?

Comment: @TonyDallimore: It could but I don't think so. The $s are there on purpose and mostly refer to the lookup array (which is static).

Answer (score 2):

My first guess was partially correct but the wrong way round.

**Problem 1**

The look up value

```
DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),31)
```

is based on the value 2011-11 and is therefore equivalent to

```
DATE(2011,11,31)
```

This will give inconsistent values.  For October it gives 31Oct11.  For November is gives 1Dec11.  To get consistent values, such as the last day of any month use:

```
DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2)+1,0)
```

**Problem 2**

If you copy your initial formula down the column you

```
=INDEX(GBP!$A$4:$BE$42,MATCH($B4,GBP!$A$4:$A$42,0),
 MATCH(DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),31),GBP!$A$3:$CE$3,1))
```

you get "#VALUE!" for all the copies because A1 becomes B1, C1, etc.

You need

```
=INDEX(GBP!$A$4:$BE$42,MATCH($B4,GBP!$A$4:$A$42,0),
 MATCH(DATE(LEFT($A$1,4),MID($A$1,6,2),31),GBP!$A$3:$CE$3,1))
                 ^ ^          ^ ^
```

**Problem 3**

In your array formula

```
=SUM(C4:C13/INDEX(GBP!$A$4:$BE$42,MATCH($B4:$B13,GBP!$A$4:$A$42,0),
 MATCH(DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),31),GBP!$A$3:$CE$3,1)))}
```

you have five ranges of which you want Excel to use two as arrays.  I cannot find anything
to suggest Excel if clever enough to guess that this what you want.

The best I can offer is to set D4 to:

```
=INDEX(GBP!$A$4:$BE$42,MATCH($B4,GBP!$A$4:$A$42,0),
 MATCH(DATE(LEFT($A$1,4),MID($A$1,6,2)+1,0),GBP!$A$3:$CE$3,1))
```

Copy this formula down the column and calculate the total with:

```
{=SUM(C4:C13/D4:D13)}
```

However, I am an adequate to good Excel VBA programmer; I am not a Excel power user.  Others may be able to tell you how to achieve what you seek.

Comment: +1 Nice analysis. I disagree with the last statement, though.

Comment: @Rachel Hettinger.  Thank you for the +1.  I have seen power users achieve amazing things with a few key strokes so I cannot claim to be one of there number.  I only learnt VBA because it was the only programming language my then employer permitted.  I have not been a professional programmer for 35 years.  My major skill today is perseverance.

Comment: @TonyDallimore: Thanks so much, this is really very helpful. And apologies, I think I ought to have removed some of the irrelevant complexity from the problem before posting, to save you from having to deal with my sloppy coding (problem 1 in particular -- for which, thanks for a great solution). 

Re problem 2, I never got as far as copying it down (have amended my original question to clarify that I was seeking to put the whole thing in a single cell) -- but you're quite right to point out that flaw :)

Re 3, too bad but perhaps I was just being overambitious!

Comment: @Michael Pavey.  Re Problem 2. My understanding of array formula is that Excel is only doing in the background what you could do on the sheet.  This understanding implies: if you cannot copy the simple formula down the column, Excel cannot copy the array formula down the column.